# Implementing the "Composite pattern" with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have an interface

```
  public interface IMessageHandler
  {
     void ProcessMessage(CanonicalModelEntityMessage message); 
  }
```

I have some concrete handlers with this sort of pattern

```
public class ThingMessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    public void ProcessMessage(Message queueMessage){
      //HandleMessage
   }
}
```

I also have a 'composite' object which will

```
public class MessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    private List<IMessageHandler> _handlers;
    public MessageHandler()
    {
        _handlers =new List<IMessageHandler>();
    }
    public void Handle(CanonicalModelEntityMessage message)
    {
        foreach (var messageHandler in _handlers)
        {
            messageHandler.Handle(message);
        }
    }

    public void Add(IMessageHandler messageHandler)
    {
        _handlers.Add(messageHandler);
    }
}
```

Each handler gets to see every message.

I believe there is a way of wiring this up with Castle, so when more handlers are added it will 'just work'.
Can you assist me in working out what changes to my code I will need, and what the installer(s) will look like?

Comment: Hi Loofer I'll try to give you a better answer later. But is seem you try to do same as me with Caliburn Micro's event aggregator. If you look at the code here https://github.com/marwijn/Caliburn.Micro.Windsor/blob/master/content/Bootstrap/EventRegistrationFacility.cs.pp you might already find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you are trying to do an event publisher / aggregator.

there are a couple of implementations of these on the net, here is an artile:

**[Event publisher](http://www.dbones.co.uk/blog/post/2011/8/domain-events-and-event-publisher)**

- code at the bottom of the article. The code is for 2.5, with a fix for 3.1+ in the comments.

Castle has a powerful mechanism which will register types based on convention, [Docs here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx). the above article makes use of this, to auto wire any type which implements the required interface.

Also, a side note:
If you want to inject all classes which implement a contract (interface) you will have to register the behaviour with castle windsor, [Example of registering a sub resolver](https://github.com/dbones/Calculator.Boxes.Windsor/blob/master/src/Calc.CommandLine/Program.cs#L81) and more information can be found [enter link description here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx#_CollectionResolver__4)

Hope this helps